# insert выборочных полей из CTE выражения

Tags: sql-server

Всем привет

Вопрос несложный, msdn не помог особо, покажите на пальцах: некий CTE запрос возвращает таблицу со значениями, которые мне нужно вставить в другую таблицу, но! ,вставлять нужно не все поля а только определённые. Это всё сделать нужно одним селектом

Comment: Что значит сделать одним селектом, т.е. осуществить выборку и вставку за запрос?

Comment: А в чем, собственно, проблема-то? INSERT же позволяет указывать поля.

Comment: пример:    WITH CTE (поле1,поле2,поле3,поле4) 
        (declare @ShiftNo varchar (10) set @ShiftNo= (Select     MAX(shiftNo) From Rus..[tbl.transakcija]) 
 --получаю последнюю смену, затем перебираю данные) 
 --здесь моя таблица с данными, 
 затем 
 INSERT INTO Rus..[tbl.inkassacija] определённых полей FROM CTE

Answer (score 3):

Речь о чем-то в этом роде?

```
CREATE TABLE #t (f1 INT, f2 INT);

WITH CTE (fld1, fld2, fld3) AS (
   SELECT 1, 2, 3
   UNION ALL
   SELECT 4, 5, 6
   UNION ALL 
   SELECT 7, 8, 9
)
INSERT INTO #t SELECT fld1, fld3 FROM CTE;

SELECT * FROM #t;
-- 1, 3
-- 4, 6
-- 7, 9

DROP TABLE #t;
```

Comment: да, но только без времянок. т.е нужно в CTE забрать данные из table1, к примеру поля a, c, e, f и перенести их table2 в поля a, b, c, d

Comment: похоже придётся приводить в соответствие CTE таблицу по кол-ву полей и по их очерёдности к вставляемой, а потом простой insert from CTE

Comment: Временная таблица тут чисто для иллюстрации. Ну и ничего же не мешает указать нужные поля в нужном порядке: `INSERT INTO #t (f2, f1) SELECT fld3, fld1 FROM CTE`